# "Restarting" a process in the same Linux terminal

Tags: c#, linux, mono

I would like my process to be able to "restart" itself without depending on shell scripts.  The following works on windows:

```
public static void Kill(bool restart)
{
    /// flush write cache, etc.
    if (restart) {
        Process.Start(path, args);
    }
    m_Process.Kill();
}
```

What happens is that a new terminal window is created and the old one exits (less than ideal, but acceptable).

My problem is that on Linux this causes an "invalid handle" exception on `/home/me/path/to/binary/[unknown]` and no new window is created.  Because no new window is created, other code I've got elsewhere in the same application chokes when it tries to do formatted output because the dimensions of Console.Window aren't initialized properly.

What is the proper way to make sure the new process attaches to the virtual terminal properly?